# При наведении в любом месте меню, появляется выпадающее меню

Tags: html, css

При наведении в любом месте меню, появляется выпадающее меню. Как это исправить? А если добавить backgroud к выпадающему меню, вылазит за длину текста обозначающее выпадающее меню (программы тренировок).

```css
@import '/styles.css/normolize.css';

body {
    font-family: 'Paytone One', sans-serif;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.section-inner {
    max-width: 1214px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

/* Каркас сайта END */

/* HEADER */
.section-menu-top {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-top: 15px;
    align-items: center;
}

.section-logo {
    color: #959597;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    transition: color 0.2s linear;

}

.section-logo:hover {
    color: #C4C4C4;
    opacity: 1;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.section-menu {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    
}

/* Цвет ссылок с плавным подсвечиванием */

.section-menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #364655;
    margin-left: 38px;
    line-height: 0.8;
    transition: color 0.2s linear;
}


/* Подсветка текста в горезонтальном меню при навидении */

.section-menu a:hover {
    color: #C4C4C4;
    opacity: 1;
}   

/* Появление выпадающего меню */

.section-menu:hover .sub-menu  {
    display: block; 
}

/* При навидении на меню появляется фон */

.sub-menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 30%;
}

/* Текст в выпадающем меню до навидения на текст */

.sub-menu a {
    color: #364655;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    display: block;
    
}

/* Меняет цвет текста в выпадающем меню */

.sub-menu a:hover {
    color: #364655;
}

/* Выделение текста в выпадающем меню при навидении */

.sub-menu a:hover {
    background-color: #f1f3f5;
    width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
            crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/profile/profile.css">
        <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,300i,700&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet">
        <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta name="discription" content="Программы тренировок для новичков">
        <meta
            name="keywords"
            content="Программа тренировок, подтягивания, отжимания, приседания, отжимания на брусьях">
        <title>Sport-defense - profile</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <section class="section-outer section-header">
            <div class="section-inner">
                <div class="section-menu-top">
                    <a class="section-logo" href="/index.html">Sport-defense</a>
                    <nav>
                        <ul class="section-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Новости</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                
                                <a href="#">Программы тренировок</a>
                            
                                <ul class="sub-menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#1">Подтягивания</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#2">Отжимания</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#3">Приседания</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>

                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Комплексы</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Рейтинговая система</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Профиль</a>
                            </li>
                        </nav>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас присутствует правило

`.section-menu:hover .sub-menu {
    display: block;
}`

Получается, при наведении на `.section-menu` (всё меню), нужно показывать `.sub-menu`. Но Вам же нужно, чтобы при наведении на конкретный пункт меню появлялось вложенное меню. Тогда следует, например, в этом правиле добавить в селектор пункт `li`, чтобы получилось

`.section-menu li:hover .sub-menu {
    display: block;
}`

[Результат на CodePen](https://codepen.io/hisbvdis/pen/QWLppgr)

Результат на StackOverflow

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Paytone One', sans-serif;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.section-inner {
  max-width: 1214px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}


/* Каркас сайта END */


/* HEADER */

.section-menu-top {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 15px;
  align-items: center;
}

.section-logo {
  color: #959597;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  transition: color 0.2s linear;
}

.section-logo:hover {
  color: #C4C4C4;
  opacity: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.section-menu {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}


/* Цвет ссылок с плавным подсвечиванием */

.section-menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #364655;
  margin-left: 38px;
  line-height: 0.8;
  transition: color 0.2s linear;
}


/* Подсветка текста в горезонтальном меню при навидении */

.section-menu a:hover {
  color: #C4C4C4;
  opacity: 1;
}


/* Появление выпадающего меню */

.section-menu li:hover .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}


/* При навидении на меню появляется фон */

.sub-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
}


/* Текст в выпадающем меню до навидения на текст */

.sub-menu a {
  color: #364655;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  display: block;
}


/* Меняет цвет текста в выпадающем меню */

.sub-menu a:hover {
  color: #364655;
}


/* Выделение текста в выпадающем меню при навидении */

.sub-menu a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f3f5;
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,300i,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="discription" content="Программы тренировок для новичков">
  <meta name="keywords" content="Программа тренировок, подтягивания, отжимания, приседания, отжимания на брусьях">
  <title>Sport-defense - profile</title>
</head>

<body>

  <section class="section-outer section-header">
    <div class="section-inner">
      <div class="section-menu-top">
        <a class="section-logo" href="/index.html">Sport-defense</a>
        <nav>
          <ul class="section-menu">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Новости</a>
            </li>
            <li>

              <a href="#">Программы тренировок</a>

              <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li>
                  <a href="#1">Подтягивания</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#2">Отжимания</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#3">Приседания</a>
                </li>
              </ul>

            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Комплексы</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Рейтинговая система</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Профиль</a>
            </li>
        </nav>
        </ul>
      </div>

</body>

</html>
```